# Use knockout to bind datepicker's mindate to another datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, datepicker

I have a lot of pairs of datepickers. The first date picker is the beginning of the interval, the second is the end of it. Logically, it is required that the first datepicker shouldn't have value more than that second and vice versa. I wrote this code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-bind="datepicker: firstDate, datepickerOptions: { endDate: secondDate }" />
<input type="text" class="datepicker" data-bind="datepicker: secondDate, datepickerOptions: { startDate: firstDate }" />
```

And JS:

```
  function model() {
        var self = this;

        self.firstDate = ko.observable();
        self.secondDate = ko.observable();
  }

  ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      //initialize datepicker with some optional options
      var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
      $(element).datepicker(options);

      //when a user changes the date, update the view model
      ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function(event) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
          value(event.date);
        }
      });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
      //when the view model is updated, update the widget
      if (widget) {
        widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (widget.date) {
          widget.setValue();
        }
      }
    }

  };

  ko.applyBindings(new model());

  $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
      format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
      language: 'ru',
      forceParse: true,
      todayBtn: true,
      clearBtn: true,
      autoclose: true
    });
  });
```

Values are get binded BUT minDate is not update on date selection. Could, please, somebody point me to my mistakes?

Here is a [broken JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z11bxeoz/12/) and a [working one](https://jsfiddle.net/z11bxeoz/16/). So as soon as I add `datepickerOptions` to my code it get broken.

Comment: try `attr:{minDate:value}`

Comment: @Rajesh, nope, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @mr.nothing, can you provide a working example? (not only html/js code - a complete jsfiddle/snippet that works and show the two datpickers working).

Comment: @Dekel, I'm total front-end newbie, but I'll do my best to do this.

Comment: If you are total front-end this is exactly what you should provide. a working front-end example. No back-end is required for that.

Comment: @Dekel, I'm frontend newbie, that's why it is not easy for me to do. It seems you saw unfinished message, that I accidentally submitted.

Comment: I guess the problem that you have is not to show the the datepicker, but to set the correct min/max dates. If this is the case - add a jsfiddle/snippet that works with the datepickers and from there it will make more sense to help.

Comment: possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511049/mindate-not-being-set-in-date-picker

Comment: You need a custom binding handler. `minDate` and `maxDate` are not valid bindings unless you've created them.

Comment: @Dekel, finally, I make jsfiddle work and reproduce my local error. Please, see updated post.

Comment: @RoyJ, I googled a lot and tried to create these handlers, but with no luck, I'll update code accordingly.

Comment: @mr.nothing, your jsfiddle doesn't work at all. Make a jsfiddle that show the basic of a working datepicker, from there I'm sure we can help.

Comment: @Dekel, I thought that the purpose of JsFiddle was to show the exact error I have. In case I remove `datepickerOptions: { endDate: secondDate }` it works and I'm able to set dates, but that functionality is already implemented and I have no problems with that. I'll update post with working and broken JsFiddles so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're feeding `ko.observable` options to your datepicker. The datepicker does not automatically know how to handle these.

You'll have to process the observable options in the `update` method. For example:

```
  var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};

  // Unwrap observable dates
  Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key) {
    options[key] = ko.unwrap(options[key]);
  });

  var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
  if (options.startDate) widget.setStartDate(options.startDate);
  if (options.endDate) widget.setEndDate(options.endDate);
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ebexf44/

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the `setStartDate` function of the **next** datepicker to the current date (of the current element) on every change:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element)
        .next('input.datepicker')
        .datepicker('setStartDate', $(element).datepicker('getDate'));
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle (mostly based on your work):
https://jsfiddle.net/ynfoj5jz/

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs. I need to bind arbitrary datepickers to each other. My example is just a simplification of what I have. In fact, my form has complex dependencies which I have to deal with.

Comment: How do you know which two datepickers are "binded"?